# Sum over list in dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm working on a dict comprehension. I start with a dict whose values are integer lists, and I want to transform it into a dictionary with the same keys, but with values that are the sum of the original lists. Here's a reproducible example:

```
n_dict = {4: [4,1,6], 3: [5,3,9], 2: [8,2,10]}
n_sum = {n_key: sum(n) for n_key in n_dict.keys() for n in n_dict[n_key]}
print(n_sum)
# expected result: {4: 11, 3: 17, 2: 20}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following type error, and I can't figure out why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    n_sum = {n_key: sum(n) for n_key in n_dict.keys() for n in n_dict[n_key]}
  File "main.py", line 3, in <dictcomp>
    n_sum = {n_key: sum(n) for n_key in n_dict.keys() for n in n_dict[n_key]}
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `n` is an individual value inside the list, e.g. the `4` in `[4, 1, 6]`, and as the error tells you that means `sum(4)` makes no sense. Why the nested loop at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the [`items`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques), to iterate over the key and the corresponding value at the same time:

```
n_dict = {4: [4, 1, 6], 3: [5, 3, 9], 2: [8, 2, 10]}
n_sum = {key: sum(value) for key, value in n_dict.items()}
print(n_sum)
```

**Output**

```
{4: 11, 3: 17, 2: 20}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to loop over the items of the list and attempt to call `sum` for each `int` in the list with a nested loop.

```
n_dict = {4: [4,1,6], 3: [5,3,9], 2: [8,2,10]}
n_sum = {n_key: sum(n_dict[n_key]) for n_key in n_dict.keys()}
print(n_sum)
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/FS9wlU)

Comment: `for n_key in n_dict.keys()` can be just `for n_key in n_dict`.